# NetSuite invoice's entity doesn't have external_id or type set

Tags: ruby, salesforce, netsuite

I'm using the [netsuite](https://github.com/NetSweet/netsuite) ruby gem and having issues with the association between an invoice and a customer, and wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

We have an `invoice` that's associated with a `customer`. We set the `external_id` on the `customer` (synced via celigo from salesforce), and can see it on the `customer` when querying it directly:

```rb
customer = NetSuite::Records::Customer.get("14829")
customer.internal_id
# "14829"
customer.external_id
# "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1"
```

However, when we query the invoice, the `external_id` and `type` on the `entity` are both `nil`:

```rb
NetSuite::Records::Invoice.get("79502").entity
# #<NetSuite::Records::RecordRef:0x00007fb30aa63cf8 @internal_id="14829", @external_id=nil, @type=nil, @attributes={:name=>"customer name"}>
```

This also prevents us from searching with `external_id`, for example:

```rb
search_params = {
  criteria: {
    basic: [{
      field: 'internalId',
      operator: 'anyOf',
      value: [ NetSuite::Records::Invoice.new(internal_id: '79502') ]
    }],
    customerJoin: [{
      field: 'internalId',
      operator: 'anyOf',
      # value: [ NetSuite::Records::Customer.new(internal_id: '14829') ]         # this works
      value: [ NetSuite::Records::Customer.new(external_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1') ] # this returns a `INVALID_KEY_OR_REF` error
    }]
  }
}
NetSuite::Records::Invoice.search(search_params)
```

I'm wondering if I miss something to get the associated `entity` from an invoice. Any insights would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using external id, you need to change this

```
customerJoin: [{
  field: 'internalId',
  operator: 'anyOf',
  value: [ NetSuite::Records::Customer.new(external_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1') ] 
}]
```

to this

```
customerJoin: [{
  field: 'externalId',
  operator: 'anyOf',
  value: [ NetSuite::Records::Customer.new(external_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1') ] 
}]
```

The external id you set is in a different field on the customer record.